Explain why the two implementations have so much performance difference
I am trying to compare the performance between Buffer::AddValueTest() and Buffer::AddValueReference() (pasted below, The full test program can be found at https://gist.github.com/find3kan0/11f2cf220ed452284db48071b1adefa1). My benchmark testing shows a surprising result (to me) that the AddValueReference is 8x faster than the AddValueTest() with 256 threads.
At 1 thread they perform pretty closely, but as thread number increases the AddValueTest() performance decay a lot faster.
I tested it on a workstation with AMD Milan (32 cores), compiled with clang 19.1.0, with the -std=c++17 -O3 flag.
Profiling shows that the AddValueTest() spend a lot more time acquiring and releasing the mutex lock. I would expect the AddValueTest() to be faster by moving those metric reporting logic out of the lock scope - or at least the performance should be roughly equivalent. What might be the source of the performance issue?
  bool AddValueTest(T val) {
    bool is_full = false;
    size_t buffer_size = 0;
    {
      absl::MutexLock lock(&mu_);
      if (stopped_) return false;

      is_full = buffer_.full();
      if (is_full) {
        buffer_.pop_front();
      }
      buffer_.push_back(std::move(val));
      buffer_size = buffer_.size();
    }

    if (is_full) {
      metric_reporter->IncDroppedValues();
    }
    metric_reporter->ReportQueueLength(buffer_size);
    return !is_full;
  }

  bool AddValueReference(T val) {
    absl::MutexLock lock(&mu_);
    if (stopped_) return false;

    bool is_full = buffer_.full();
    if (is_full) {
      buffer_.pop_front();
      metric_reporter->IncDroppedValues();
    }

    buffer_.push_back(std::move(val));
    metric_reporter->ReportQueueLength(buffer_.size());
    return !is_full;
  }


Look at the assembly language produced - perhaps one version manages to inline/precalculate/skip the Fibonacci series?

No.  Even without the Fib the perf result is similar.  I did inspect the assembly code but I didn't spot anything obvious (but my assembly skill is limited).
When tested with single thread the 2 impl has similiar performance. The AddValueTest perforamnce decay a lot faster as thread number increases.

Maybe, O.T.: bool buffer_size = 0; The name and the value indicate that bool might be a typo and should have been size_t instead.

Thanks @Scheff'sCat.  The bool buffer_size is a typo and does not impact the benchmark result.

How are you compiling your code? Are compiler (and linker) optimizations enabled?

Maybe the atomcs use mutexes in the implementation, but since you already have a lock it can operate faster, rather three distinct lock-unlocks? Could you [edit] in a link to https://www.godbolt.org/ or similar so people can try out a working example?
